# UIView AnimateWithDuration and UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I'm trying to create an unwind segue with the page curl animation. I've followed a tutorial I found only to have the destination view controller call `segueForUnwindingToViewController` to return an instance of my custom segue class. However, at best it just instantly changes to the appropriate view without a delay or any animation.

Any help would be appreciated.

The contents of `perform`:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp 
                 animations:^{} 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){ 
                     [destinationViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
                     [sourceViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:NULL];
}];
```

Comment: Please provide the link to the tutorial that you followed.

Comment: http://blog.dadabeatnik.com/2013/10/13/custom-segues/
Mainly the parts on unwind segues.